# find all files containing all specified words

Tags: grep, find, search

How can I use `grep` and/or `find` to find all files which have all of specfied words?

So something like

```
grep -R -words 'Quick', 'Lazy', 'Jumped' /
```

would return all files on system with words Quick, Lazy and Jumped.

Is there any support or should I be looking to write my own script?

Comment: You should read the manual pages for the utilities you're asking about. The answer would then become clear. Try `man grep` for starters.

Comment: @ThomasN: While it’s true that question-askers should read the manual pages for the utilities they’re asking about, your comment is inappropriately snarky. This is a tricky question. Can you provide an answer that’s “clear” from `man grep`? (No fair peeking at the duplicate.)

Comment: Well, I didn't look at the duplicate, but using the `-f` switch to provide the pattern(s) to look for and using the -R switch to recursively look from whatever point the poster desires should cover the requirements of the question. Seems like all that would need to be done would be to fiddle with the pattern match. You could use something like ".*Quick.*Lazy.*Jumped.*", but you would soon burn through most of your memory and computation power performing that search across an entire machine. More research would probably have helped.